How to skip submodules with `repo forall`?
Many commands in the repo tool do have some submodule support via flags like --fetch-submodules, --submodules... but nothing is mentioned in repo help forall or repo forall --help.
Yet when I run repo forall -c command then it traverses through the submodules. Why is that? How can I run a shell command only on repos managed by repo tool, specified in the manifest? Variables like $REPO_PROJECT or $REPO_REMOTE don't help as they don't expand to something differentiable
Repo version:
repo launcher version 1.27
       (from /usr/bin/repo)
       (currently at 1.13.7-40-gd92076d)
repo User-Agent git-repo/1.13.7-40-gd92076d (Linux) git/2.17.1 Python/2.7.17
git 2.17.1
git User-Agent git/2.17.1 (Linux) git-repo/1.13.7-40-gd92076d
Python 2.7.17 (default, Jul  1 2022, 15:56:32)
[GCC 7.5.0]


What command did you run? I tried repo forall -p -c 'git log -1 --pretty=oneline' and it printed only the main repo's log.

@ElpieKay any command, like repo forall -p -c pwd or the one you commented. The easiest way to see is just repo forall -p -c 'ls -d .gitmodules'

My manifest has one repository foo that has submodules. I try the command. It prints the output of foo only and skipped all of its submodules. Or did I misunderstand the question?

@ElpieKay in my case repo forall -p -c pwd or repo forall -p -c 'git log -1 --pretty=oneline' will print all the contents of the submodules

Are the paths of these submodules in .repo/project.list?

@ElpieKay yes, they're all in that file. Maybe it's related to the version because this is old and not compatible with the current upstream repo tool anymore

If the submodules are also in .repo/project.list, they are not git-submodules but nested-repositories that happen to lie in the main repository. If they are really git-submodules, you should remove them from the manifest file.
